# how to pass parameters with custom lsp command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I need to get function object or related URI to doc line on which command was triggered inside function which looks like this:

```
@LSP_SERVER.command("unittest_generator.run")
def generate_test_template(params: lsp.ExecuteCommandParams) -> None:
```